# Create mysql trigger on update database

Tags: mysql, triggers

Database 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `vote_name` (
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Database 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `vote_main` (
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `up` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `down` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I received a request for UPDATE on `vote_name` only parameter 'vote'  -
(1)`UPDATE vote_name SET vote=vote+1 WHERE name=$name`
Automatically picks the **last** line of `vote_main` which comprises `name`(from update request(1)) and update `up` form `vote_main`..

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER UPDATE ON vote_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.vote_name  <> OLD.vote_name  THEN  
        UPDATE vote_name SET vote=vote+1 WHERE name=$name
    END IF;
END;
```

Use this code .

Comment: I need update `vote_main` ..
If changed `vote` form `vote_name` auto update and `up`+1 from `vote_main`

Comment: If you received this query to MySQL
(1)`UPDATE vote_name SET vote=vote+1 WHERE name=$name` auto (2)query `UPDATE vote_main SET up=up+1 WHERE name=name` (name = form (1) query)